# android only show first viewpager inside recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter, viewpage

i have a viewpager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter inside recyclerview
and its show only the first row in recyclerview
please help me

viewpager adapter:
    public  class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

```
    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        Log.e("fragmentManager",fragmentManager.toString());
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment currentFragment;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                currentFragment=new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                currentFragment=new SecondFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                currentFragment=new ThirdFragment();
                break;
            default:
                currentFragment=new FirstFragment();
                break;
        }

        return currentFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

recyclerview adapter:

```
public class JobAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobAdapter.JobHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> mJobList = new ArrayList<>();

    public JobAdapter(List<String> mJobList,Context context) {
        this.mJobList = mJobList;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public JobHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.find_job_line_content, parent, false);
        return new JobHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final JobHolder holder, int position) {
        configurePagerHolder(holder, position);
    }

    private void configurePagerHolder(JobHolder holder, int position) {
        //Job job= mJobList.get(position);
        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager());
        holder.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        holder.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        Log.e("configurePagerHolder",position+"");

    }

    public int getItemCount() {``
        return mJobList.size();
    }


    public class JobHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ViewPager viewPager;
        public JobHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            viewPager=(ViewPager)itemView.findViewById(R.id.slidesPager);
        }

    }
```

main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    JobAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.find_jobs_recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        adapter = new JobAdapter(list,this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you found workaround?

Comment: yes, i created viewpager id progrematically, and it work

Comment: Please, explain where did you setup viewpager id programmatically ? How did you solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but it might help some people...

Try using ViewPager2 ( an improved version of ViewPager) : https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2

In my case it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change viewpager id in every cell

```
binding.viewPager.id = binding.viewPager.id+position
```